# running a function after a google map call has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to collect location data from my users as they're entering other details in a form. So I have a google map which users can move a marker about on but I also have an input which they can type a location into.

When they click to submit the form, I want to first geocode the location they have typed and update the hidden lat lng inputs in my form before the submit actually takes place.

I know there's lots of info online but I've read loads of tutorials but I'm struggling to understand or at least to apply the tutorials to my situation.

So when a user clicks submit I want to run geocode and only submit the form when geocode is definitely finished.

```
$('.submitButton').click(function () {
    geocode();
            $("#searchForm").submit();//Then submit when geocode finishes
});
```

And the geocode function

```
function geocode(){
 geocoder.geocode({
        address: $('#address').val()
    }, function(results, status){
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
         var geoPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            map.setCenter(geoPoint);
            circle.setCenter(geoPoint);
            marker.setPosition(geoPoint);
           $('#lat').val(geoPoint.lat());
           $('#lng').val(geoPoint.lng());
        } else{
            alert("Can not geolocate this address.");
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone explain to me what I need to do in simple javascript dummy language? THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Geocoding service is asynchronous, `geocode()` will return almost immediately and `$("#searchForm").submit()` will submit what is available and that will be wrong (old or undefined data).

You have to move form submit call to `geocode()` function just after settings of lat/lng values:

```
    ...
        marker.setPosition(geoPoint);
       $('#lat').val(geoPoint.lat());
       $('#lng').val(geoPoint.lng());

       $("#searchForm").submit();
    } else{
    ...
```

If, as you said in comment, `geocode()` function is also used somewhere else then you will have to write another function with similar functionality or prepare two different callback function.

Comment: The problem is that I use that geocode function elsewhere, and I don't want to submit a form in the other instance. I guess I should just make a new goecodefunction?

Comment: Another option is to use some flag and set it to true when you want to submit the form. And clear it after that.

Comment: You can also make different callback function for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass an optional argument to geocode, e.g. a function that will be executed on success:

```
$('.submitButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //call geocode and pass the desired function as argument
    geocode(function(){$("#searchForm").submit();});

    return false;        
});

function geocode(fnc){
 geocoder.geocode({
        address: $('#address').val()
    }, function(results, status){
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
         var geoPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                               results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            map.setCenter(geoPoint);
            circle.setCenter(geoPoint);
            marker.setPosition(geoPoint);
           $('#lat').val(geoPoint.lat());
           $('#lng').val(geoPoint.lng());

           //check  if the fnc-argument is a function, 
           //when it does, execute the function 
           if($.type(fnc)==='function'){
             fnc();
           }

        } else{
            alert("Can not geolocate this address.");
        }
    });
}
```